# Show some default text if return value is null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a linq query.In here when **item.nValue** sometimes comes as a empty string.I need to check if nValue comes as a empty string article value need to show "OLD RECORD".

I want to do this in this linq query..

```
var article = _newsList.Where(e => e.Id == Guid.Parse(item.nValue)).Select(e => e.NewsName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Steve Sometimes item.nValue comes as a Empty String.Then i need to show in the article value is "OLD RECORD"

Comment: first ,as i know you can not parse in a Linq query. it means you should parse a null/empty value before you use it in linq query coz linq statement can not recognize it. second , it is a little confuse for me about what does mean old record and what you want.

Comment: @AminSaadati normally if item.nValue comes as a empty string because those records are old.. thats why i need to show this.

Comment: you can check item.nValue is empty before this query line and set `article` to "OLD RECORD". but I think your intention is something else. isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var article = _newsList.Where(e => e.Id == (item.nValue==""?Guid.Parse(item.nValue):"OLD RECORD"))
.Select(e => e.NewsName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question,So

```
var article = _newsList.Where(e => e.Id == Guid.Parse(item.nValue)).DefaultIfEmpty(yourDefaultValue).Select(e => e.NewsName).FirstOrDefault();
```

probably `DefaultIfEmpty` can help you.Please test it.

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the specified value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty

Comment: It throws an exception by item.nValue equals the empty string.

Comment: @IvanR. I told @TechGuy about it that this error will happen `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the ..` in his first post's comment,But he probably knows about it and his problem was about how to set a default value in a linq statement NOT about a parsing `Guid.Parse` . probably he will parse nValue before use it Linq statement

Answer (score 2):

`item.nValue` variable is not from LINQ collection so you can try:

```
        var article = "OLD RECORD";
        if (Guid.TryParse(item.nValue, out Guid articleId))
        {
             article = _newsList.Where(e => e.Id == articleId).Select(e => e.NewsName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```